# Shiny Plotly reactive data plot

Tags: r, plot, shiny, plotly

I've put together this Shiny app from tutorial and examples, and I've become stuck. My aim is to make the plot reactive, so that the data points in 'uval$df' are plotted, meaning that selected points will be removed from the graph, and it can't be selected twice. How do I do this? (I've got a feeling it's something lacking in my basic understanding)

Thanks!

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(12,plotlyOutput("plot"),
           verbatimTextOutput("txtout1"),
           verbatimTextOutput("txtout2"),
           verbatimTextOutput("txtout3"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
x<-c(1,2,34,2,1,23,24)   
y<-c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70)
df<-data.frame(x,y)
vector.is.empty <- function(x) return(length(x) ==0 )

K <-reactive({
  event_data("plotly_selected",source = "B")
})

M<-reactive({
  K()[,c("x","y")]
})

values <- reactiveValues()
values$df <- data.frame(x = numeric(0), y = numeric(0))
newEntry <- observeEvent(K(),priority = 1,{
    new0 <- isolate(M())
    isolate(values$df <- rbind(values$df, new0))
})

uval <- reactiveValues()
uval$df <- df
newEntry1 <- observeEvent({values$df},priority = 2,{
  new1 <- isolate(data.frame(values$df))
  isolate(uval$df <- setdiff(df,new1))
})

output$plot <- renderPlotly({
  plot_ly(x = df$x, y = df$y, mode = "markers",source="B") %>%
    layout(dragmode =  "select", title = "Original Plot", font=list(size=10))
})

output$txtout1 <- renderPrint({
  if(vector.is.empty(K())) "Click and drag across points" else M()
})

output$txtout2 <- renderPrint({
  uval$df
})

output$txtout3 <- renderPrint({
  values$df
})

}

shinyApp(ui, server, options = list(display.mode = "showcase"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, as I thought.

```
plot_ly(uval$df, x = x, y = y, mode = "markers",source="B")
```